# Send ctrl-c to break kubectl+sed output, reliable

Tags: sed, kubectl, ctrl

When using sed to format kubectl log output, e.g. like this:

`kubectl log mypod -f |sed -u 's/\\n/\n/g; s/\\t/\t/g'`

Sending <kbd>CTRL - C</kbd> often doesn't break the command, when there is currently no output. Is there a way to reliable break the command? Maybe I'm missing some command options?

Answer (score 1):

You can break the command using [timeout](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html), for example:

```
$ timeout -k 1 5 kubectl log mypod -f |sed -u 's/\\n/\n/g; s/\\t/\t/g'
```

This command will be terminated in 5 or killed after 6 seconds.

Alternatively you can add `kill` command to terminate it, for example:

```
$ kubectl log mypod -f |sed -u 's/\\n/\n/g; s/\\t/\t/g' & 
$ kill -9 $!
```

`$!` contains process ID of the most recently executed background command.

Comment: Alternatively, you can suspend the current process by pressing `Ctrl+z` and then kill it using `kill -9 %%` or `kill -9 %+ ` ( http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html#SEC33 )

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution: I call `kubectl log ...` inside a bash script, and catch <kbd>CTRL - C</kbd> with `trap ctrl_c INT`. Inside `ctrl_c()`, I kill the kubectl process by its id, which I have previously stored in a variable.